# Get Stock Price from Morningstar / BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, stock

so it's happening. Finally, I have to ask my first question on Stackoverflow.

I'm trying to get the current price of a stock from Morningstar (https://www.morningstar.com/stocks/xnas/tsla/quote.html) and I am using Beautifulsoup for this.

In the HTML code there is an unique ID ("message-box-price"). I want to use it to get the Price after it, but unfortunately I'm not able to find a solution. It would be nice if somebody can help me.

My code to get the site is:

```
import bs4
import requests

res = requests.get('https://www.morningstar.com/stocks/xnas/tsla/quote.html')
res.raise_for_status()
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'lxml')
```

I have tried many different methods but I thought these were the most promising ones:

Number 1:

```
price = soup.find(id='message-box-price')
price2 = price.find_next()
print(price2)
```

Number 2:

```
price = soup.select("#message-box-price")
price2 = price.find_all_next()
print(price2)
```

Number 3:

```
price = soup.find_all(id="message-box-price")
print(price)
```

Also I have tried some variations of it and used .text to get the values for example.

Errors have been:

- AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_previous'
- AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'text'
- TypeError: select() got an unexpected keyword argument 'attrs'
- Or I just got an empty list back -> [ ]

Comment: This won't work by using `requests` directly on that link, as i can see there it loads the data you looking for via javascript, so you either use `selenium` or search the source from where the results are called (AJAX).

Answer (score 1):

The page is dynamic. You could use Selenium to open the page, let it render, then grab the info:

```
import pandas as pd
import bs4 
from selenium import webdriver 

url = 'https://www.morningstar.com/stocks/xnas/tsla/quote.html'

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get(url)

html = browser.page_source

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')

price = soup.find('div', {'id':'message-box-price'})
price2 = price.text.strip()
print(price2)

browser.close()
```

**Output:**

```
print(price2)
$312.21
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. If I can't scrap this price without selenium than maybe it's better to use pyautogui and download the whole history (see my answer below).

Answer (score 0):

Like @chitown88 and @rukh-ta mentioned in their answers, to get this price, I have to use selenium. In this case I am better off to use pyautogui to download the whole price history of the stock as CSV.

My code to do this looks like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import pyautogui

url = 'https://www.morningstar.com/stocks/xnas/tsla/quote.html'

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get(url)
time.sleep(7)

pyautogui.click(139, 833, button='left')
time.sleep(10)
pyautogui.click(973, 289, button='left')
time.sleep(2)
pyautogui.click(1649, 236, button='left')
time.sleep(1)

pyautogui.typewrite(['down'])
time.sleep(1)
pyautogui.typewrite(['enter'])

browser.close()
```

If someone has an easier and/or faster way, please feel free to mention it.

(Also, if you wonder why I'm not using any other stock api. The thing is, that I'm doing a project where I'm using the stock tickers of the Morningstar universe. For this reason, to get the prices also from Morningstar is more efficient cause the tickers oftentimes vary and in an automated process a lot of the requests are failing.)